# Opening current MS Access report in Word

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to open a MS Access report in MS Word (for editing).
The Access report is opened using the MS Access application, and some fields in the report are filled using the "Form_Load()" function in the VBA of the Report. (See code below)

```
    FactuurInfo.setDebiteur GBL_debiteurId
'''GBL_factuurId = FactuurInfo.getInfo("factuurId")

'Set date & location
Datum_txt.Caption = "Ede, " & Format(Date, "dd MMMM yyyy")
'Set left part of header
'''Header_left_info.Caption = "Dental Zorg/Incasso" & vbNewLine & _
'''                            "2004253/RA" & vbNewLine & _
'''                            ""
Header_left_info.Caption = FactuurInfo.getInfo("zaak") & vbNewLine & _
                            FactuurInfo.getInfo("referentie") & vbNewLine & _
                            ""
'Set right part of header
Header_right_info.Caption = "Mr C.A. Hage" & vbNewLine & _
                            "0318 - 657635" & vbNewLine & _
                            "0318 - 657640" & vbNewLine & _
                            "harmsen@hageadvocaten.nl"

'Get text from templates table
Dim maintext As String
query = "SELECT * FROM Templates WHERE Id = " & GBL_templateId
Set DB = CurrentDb
Set rst = DB.OpenRecordset(query)
rst.MoveLast
'Fill fields
maintext = rst.Fields("Tekst").value

'replace keywords
Dim str As String, openKeyWord As String, closeKeyWord As String
Dim openPos As Integer
Dim closePos As Integer
Dim midBit As String
openKeyWord = "\["
closeKeyWord = "\]"
Do While (InStr(maintext, openKeyWord))
    openPos = InStr(maintext, openKeyWord)
    closePos = InStr(maintext, closeKeyWord)
    midBit = Mid(maintext, openPos + Len(openKeyWord), closePos - openPos - Len(closeKeyWord))
    maintext = Replace(maintext, openKeyWord & midBit & closeKeyWord, FactuurInfo.getInfo(midBit))
Loop

'replace newlines
maintext = Replace(maintext, "\n", vbNewLine)
Maintext_txt.Caption = maintext

'open in word
If GBL_openInWord Then
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "testReport", acFormatRTF, strFolderName & "/testReport.rtf", True
End If
```

In the end of the function it opens the report in Word. But instead of opening the report with it's fields filled with the code above, it opens the Report as it is before those fields are filled. The 'filled' Report is still opened in access, so i know the code works.

Can anyone please help me? I have been struggling with this for some time now.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but have you tried changing `Form_Load()` to `Form_Open()`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'fill the fields first' - code writing data to record? Edit question to provide that code.

Comment: @Gijs van der Meijde the `DoCmd` is working correctly.  You've told it to output the report into an RTF formatted file. it is.  You haven't filled out the fields.  Ditto on @June7's comment.

Comment: RTFs are document reports so they would have fields populated if there is a recordsource (table/query) behind the report.

Comment: Do you mean `Report_Load()` instead of `Form_Load()` if you're referring to the VBA code behind the Report (not a Form)? Does the report look correct (is the data there) in Print Preview view? Can you post the code in the report's module?

Comment: Sorry, yeah i meant Report_Load()

The functions is triggered, it shows the 'filled' Report in access. But then it opens in Word and i get the default (non-filled) report again.
Is there a way to add parameters to the 'DoCmd.OutputTo' function (so the generated report knows what to do)?

Comment: No. You're probably dealing with an unbound report, so the only way to get a populated version is to first open it in Access. Better yet, you can adjust the current code to find a back door, but you need to include the `Report_Load()` code in your question.

Comment: I added most of the Report_Load() function and rephrased the question a bit. I hope it is a little more clear what i am trying to do now.

Comment: 1)  If there are mistakes in the question, do not just add corrections in the comments. Just like you added code, please edit the question directly with other corrections like the name of the function. 2) Please include the function name and delimiters in the code.

Answer (score 0):

A report is fully generated only after multiple events are triggered and completed. The processing of Access Reports can be very finicky and the event order is not always intuitive.  In fact, the event order is different for Report View vs Print Preview because the later ensures complete pagination, while the on-screen view does not generate pages.  It is best practice to NOT include code in report events that are not directly related to report formatting. In particular, `Report_Load()` runs before other event, so it is **very premature** to output the report during this event. Despite assigning values to report controls, no layout has been completed during this event.

Further, the process of generating the on-screen view will be separate from generation of the file output from 'DoCmd.OutputTo`, so the fact that the report looks okay on screen is a separate issue from the generation of the RTF file.  (I'm surprised that the code does not produce errors from recursively trying to save the file output.)

Instead, call `DoCmd.OutputTo` from code outside the report module, perhaps from a Form.